# Insert relational data in SQL Alchemy with API queries in Python

Tags: python, json, api, sqlalchemy, python-requests

Maybe my previous question was too much long and endless to answer, sorry for that... I will try to be more specific shortening my previous question

I can extract from an API query (json format as output) the following information:

GENE1

```
Experiment1     
Experiment2     
Experiment3     
Experiment4
```

GENE2

```
Experiment5     
Experiment2     
Experiment3     
Experiment8     
Experiment9
```

> [...]

So I obtain genes and their related experiments in which they have been studied... One gene can have more than one experiment, and 1 experiment can have more than one gene (many to many)

I have this schema in SQL Alchemy:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, Date, ForeignKey, Table, Float
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship, backref
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
import requests

Base = declarative_base()

Genes2experiments = Table('genes2experiments',Base.metadata,                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  Column('gene_id', String, ForeignKey('genes.id')),                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  Column('experiment_id', String, ForeignKey('experiments.id'))
)

class Genes(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'genes'
    id = Column(String(45), primary_key=True)
    experiments = relationship("Experiments", secondary=Genes2experiments, backref="genes")
    def __init__(self, id=""):
        self.id= id
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<genes(id:'%s')>" % (self.id)

class Experiments(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'experiments'
    id = Column(String(45), primary_key=True)
    def __init__(self, id=""):
        self.id= id
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<experiments(id:'%s')>" % (self.id)

def setUp():
    global Session
    engine=create_engine('mysql://root:password@localhost/db_name?charset=utf8', pool_recycle=3600,echo=False)
    Session=sessionmaker(bind=engine)

def add_data():   
    session=Session()
    for i in range(0,1000,200):
        request= requests.get('http://www.ebi.ac.uk/gxa/api/v1',params={"updownInOrganism_part":"brain","rows":200,"start":i})
        result = request.json
        for item in result['results']:
            gene_to_add = item['gene']['ensemblGeneId']            
    session.commit()
    session.close()       


setUp()
add_data()
```

With this code I just add to my database all the genes from the API query to the Genes table...

1st question: how and when should I add the experiments information to keep their relationship someway???

2nd question: should I add a new secondary relationship in the Experiments class, as in the Genes class, or is it enough putting just one?

Thank you

(for more context/info: [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15899565/how-to-insert-relational-data-many-to-many-in-sql-alchemy-by-means-of-api-quer))

Answer (score 3):

1. Whenever you records the results of an experiment, or even when you *plan* an experiment, you can already add instances to the database and the relationships as well.
2. having `backref` will effectively add the other side of the relationship, so that having an instance of `Experiments`, you can get the Genes[] via `my_experiment.genes`

*Note: I would remove plural from the names of your entities: `class Gene, class Experiment` instead of `class Genes, class Experiments`*.